# Example for executing a WMI method from Windows Driver

Tags: windows, wmi, drivers, wdk

I am looking for an example of how to execute WMI method from Windows Driver.
I need to call *TestFunction* from class *MY_WMI_CLASS*

```
[WMI, dynamic: ToInstance, provider("xxx"), Locale("some"), Description("test xxx"), guid("{someguidhere}")]
class MY_WMI_CLASS
{
    [key, read] string InstanceName;
    [read] boolean Active;
    [WmiMethodId(1), 
          Implemented, 
          Description("Test xxx")] 
          void TestFunction([out, Description("Test f")] uint32 Data);
};
```

MSDN says I have to call

> IoWMIQueryAllData, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550453(v=vs.85).aspx

and

> IoWMIExecuteMethod, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550438(v=vs.85).aspx

functions. IoWMIExecuteMethod function has an InstanceName parameter which I don't know how to get.

```
NTSTATUS IoWMIExecuteMethod(
  _In_    PVOID           DataBlockObject,
  _In_    PUNICODE_STRING InstanceName,
  _In_    ULONG           MethodId,
  _In_    ULONG           InBufferSize,
  _Inout_ PULONG          OutBufferSize,
  _Inout_ PUCHAR          InOutBuffer
);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you please share the MSDN link so that we can give a better solution?

Comment: added more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on my own question.

```
    PVOID       wmiObject = NULL;
    ULONG       allocSize = 100;
    UCHAR       pBuffer[100] = ;

    //Open block
    rc = IoWMIOpenBlock(&guid, WMIGUID_EXECUTE, &wmiObject);

    //get instance name
    rc = IoWMIQueryAllData(wmiObject, &allocSize, pBuffer);


    WNODE_ALL_DATA *pWNode = (WNODE_ALL_DATA*)pBuffer;
    ULONG offset = *((PULONG)(pBuffer + pWNode->OffsetInstanceNameOffsets));
    PWCHAR str = (PWCHAR)(pBuffer + offset + 2);

    UNICODE_STRING uniInstanceName = { 0 };
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniInstanceName, str);

    UINT8 data[100];
    size = 100;

    //execute a method 
    rc = IoWMIExecuteMethod(wmiObject, &uniInstanceName, 1, 0, &size, data);
```